# MineSweeper Game

Tags: java, user-interface, actionlistener

This mine sweeper game is the conventional game however the person starts with three lives and can get three more if he can find the shield. Also an immortality can also be found which is very rare and gives the user infinite amount of lives.

So the problem is that when I reset the game and for example click on a a bomb then I lose more than one life. However at the beginning everything works perfectly. This problem is not only for that but for mostly everything.

So here is the code :

```
    if (e.getSource() == btnReset) {
       // miss = 0;
       // System.out.println(miss);
        getMines();
        lives = 3;
        System.out.println(" lives = " +lives);
        for (int x = 0; x < BOARD_HEIGHT; x++) 
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < BOARD_WIDTH; y++) 
            {

                btn[x][y].addActionListener(this);
                btn[x][y].setBackground(null);


            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: That's a very vague problem statement and a lot of code. Narrow down the problem to something more specific and only include the code relevant to the problem.

Comment: I don't get how "So the problem is that when I reset the game and for example click on a a bomb then I lose more than one life." is vague... its very specific

Answer (score 1):

In your "reset" action branch, you are doing this...

```
btn[x][y].addActionListener(this);
```

If the `ActionListener` hasn't previously been removed, you will be adding ANOTHER `ActionListener`, so the next time you click that button, your `ActionListener` will be called multiple times...

Personally, I'd find away that didn't involve adding/removing listeners, but I'm not sure that's feasible at this stage, instead, you should first remove yourself as an `ActionListener` before adding yourself again...

```
btn[x][y].removeActionListener(this);
btn[x][y].addActionListener(this);
```

Comment: I tested your fix this indeed fixes this issue.

Comment: Thank you, but I think it's removeActionListener, anyways it works! thank you.

Comment: Sorry, typing on the iPad never seems to work :P